# Making a clickable grid of cells in js/html/css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a grid for a game similar to tic tac toe except you are looking to get 5 in a row instead of 3 which means I need more than 9 cells for the grid. I need a graph paper-like grid and each cell of the grid is clickable and turns into a certain color when click. Each cell needs to have an individual tag because I will need it later when the program needs to determine if the player achieves five in a row. For example, the 2nd cell on the first row is cell[2][1].

What I have so far:

```
for (var x=0;x <gridWidth; x=x+10){  //each cell is 10px by 10px
    for (var y=0; y<gridHeight; y=y+10){
        return Cell[x][y];   //I am not sure how to print out a cell at each of these 'coordinates'.
    };
};
```

Comment: We're going to need substantially more code than this to help. All you have right there is something that loops through each cell and returns something, but since it returns, it actually only does the first one. It would be helpful if you could set up a demo that works with what you have in JSFiddle or Codepen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: I have modified the code bellow to generate the grid dinamically.

---

**NOTE**: Please, note that this answer uses jQuery.

---

First, you can create a function to generate the grid. It will loop the rows and columns as you were trying to do, but it will return a string with the correct HTML code. You will use jQuery to append that HTML string as a HTML element to the document.

BTW, you shouldn't try to set the size of the cells with javascript, for that you have CSS.

When a user click on a cell, you can use jQuery `.index()` to retrieve the index of the cell and, from there, the row and the column it belongs to.

Last, to change the color of a cell you just edit its `background-color` property.

Something like this can help you to start:

```js
function generateGrid( rows, cols ) {
    var grid = "<table>";
    for ( row = 1; row <= rows; row++ ) {
        grid += "<tr>"; 
        for ( col = 1; col <= cols; col++ ) {      
            grid += "<td></td>";
        }
        grid += "</tr>"; 
    }
    return grid;
}

$( "#tableContainer" ).append( generateGrid( 5, 5) );

$( "td" ).click(function() {
    var index = $( "td" ).index( this );
    var row = Math.floor( ( index ) / 5) + 1;
    var col = ( index % 5 ) + 1;
    $( "span" ).text( "That was row " + row + " and col " + col );
    $( this ).css( 'background-color', 'red' );
});
```

```css
td {
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span>Select a cell!</span>
<div id="tableContainer"></div>
```

Comment: I'm always fine with a downvote :) but I would like to know the reason in case I can improve my answer. So far I see, it is doing what the OP asked for.

Comment: (Note: I did not downvote.) **A personal opinion:** OP's level of effort seems less than minimal, and we should be helping them resolve issues with their code, instead of writing it for them. **And some suggestions for improving your response:** jQuery isn't necessary for such a trivial task, and OP didn't mention it. I'm not saying it's not a valid approach, and is fine as an alternate method, but it should be presented as such. Also, building strings for HTML is messy. I recommend using document.createElement and element.appendChild to construct true DOM elements and structure at runtime.

Comment: @TheJim01: Thank you for your comment. I need to say that, actually, you are right. I should have recommend (as samanime did) a further research/work before start to coding for him. Regarding jQuery, you are also right, I didn't even notice that the OP didn't tag it. Now, honestly, I'm lazy to rewrite it in vanilla js, so I just added a warning. But regarding building HTML I don't think there is a clear winner. Efficiency depends heavily on the situation and the browser, and, maintenance and readability... I'd say is a matter of taste. Maybe DOM methods are more clear, but also more verbose.